# iMovie costs money now?

Tags: mac, imovie

I bought my computer in 2014 last fall and this summer I brought it in to get a factory reset (to take out everything I had done). When I brought it home I realized that iMovie was deleted and I searched it up to see that it would now cost money... I wanted to know if there was any way to recover iMovie or get it for free.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar experience.

iMovie came with my MacBook Pro when I bought it in 2011, but I could not update it in 2014.

I contacted Apple Support, who checked the MacBook ID and restored the purchase.

Answer (score 2):

Go to App Store > Purchases and click the cloud icon next to iMovie (or any other app that you would wish to download) to download it again for free. If for any reason iMovie is not present in Purchases, then, unfortunately you will be required to buy it again.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you may have to go to the apple store and ask them to restore your purchase :((